# How to swap displaying on Adafruit TFT back to HDMI

Tags: adafruit

I’m new here. Recently got the adafruit tft display, tried it out but now want to swap back to HDMI output to display on monitor as before.

Original instructions : https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-mini-pitft-135x240-color-tft-add-on-for-raspberry-pi/1-3-240x240-kernel-module-install

How do I swap displays back to HDMI!

Comment: how did you swap it to the TFT display?

Comment: Followed a tutorial provided by Adafruit : It’s not clear how I could swap it back :(

Comment: If you want help tell us what **YOU** did. These Adafruit "tutorials" are incomprehensible. Better still would be to restore from your backup before you did it.